# git clone can not reach host inside docker container

Tags: git, ssh, docker, git-clone

I met this problem long time ago and can not solve it at all. Can anyone give me some help?

I created a docker container, and then inside docker, I want to clone an internal git repository:

```
git clone git@git.xxx.net:ngcsc/ngcsc.git
```

And I got this error:

```
ssh: connect to host git.xxx.net port 22: No route to host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I use curl https://git.xxx.net,
I also met error:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to git.xxx.net:443; No route to host
```

I can curl other https website, such as curl https://www.google.com

I don't know why some internal website can be reached inside docker, some not. Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Could be relevant here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31328031/6309 and http://askubuntu.com/a/136414/5470 and http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/11/four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/

Answer (score 1):

I think since you are using the ssh url for git clone, you would have generate a ssh key and register the same on the git portal.

[GitHub ssh registration](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)

Then you would have to include the ssh key inside the docker container and do `ssh-add keyfile`

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: I guess the AWS instance I used didn't allowed outgoing SSH, using HTTPS fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have mapped the relevant ports when you start the container, generally ssh use port `22` or `443`, so you can simply map both them.

```
docker run -it -p 22:22 -p 443:443 IMAGE_ID
```

Second, inside the docker, you should generate an ssh key-pair and register the git portal you are using. Simply you can use command `ssh-keygen` to generate an new key pair.

Comment: how do you manage this if you are tearing up and tearing down the container?