# Share localhost with docker container

Tags: docker, localhost

I have a localhost application running on port 5001.

I also have a docker container running that I want to be able to access the application described above but I receive a connection refused error.

I imagine this is because the container needs additional configuration to access the application via the port 5001.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use `host` network mode: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/network-settings.

Comment: Or use an [alias on the loopback interface](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39840653/1318694)

Comment: Which OS is this for? Linux with native Docker, or Windows/Mac with Docker-Machine?