# How to let docker container access host network port

Tags: docker

I want to connect to my local host service from a docker container. I am using docker for mac. I checked this link [How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container) but when I run `ip addr show docker0` in the docker container. I got `ip addr show docker0` error response. Below is all the network devices on my docker container.

```
# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: ip_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1428 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: ip6_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
7: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
8: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
9: ip6gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1448 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/gre6 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
238: eth0@if239: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:14:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.2/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe14:2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Which one is my local host address?

Comment: Try eth0. The rest are tunnels as far as I can see

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special Mac-only DNS name `docker.for.mac.localhost`, this will resolve to the host IP.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-macos

Answer (score 0):

You can `docker run --network host ...` to let docker container access host ports. Or use option `network_mode` in `docker-compose.yaml`. But this mode can be a security issue if you use an untrusted docker image.