# Docker: How to curl local server xyz.example.com running on host machine from within a docker container

Tags: curl, docker

On my host machine, I have a server `xyz.example.com` running on nginx. It is not dockerized and not accessible to the outside world, it is simply used for local dev environment.

I would like to be able to access it from within a docker container.

For example, I'd like to be able to do the following from within my docker container:

```
curl xyz.example.com
```

and to see the same output I see when I run the command on my host machine.

Also, I am using docker-compose.

Comment: What is the error that your are getting?

Comment: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host`

Comment: are you using docker-compose?

Comment: Yes, I am using docker-compose.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but did you ever resolve this?  I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your container doesn't know about your `xyz.example.com` because It is declared in your host's `/etc/host` (you said it is a private server)?

Then you could add the host as `extra_host`:

```
services:
  some-service:
    extra_hosts:
      - "xyz.example.com:HOST_BRIDGE_IP"
```

The [`extra_host`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts) will add hostname mappings in container's `/etc/host`.

And run your `docker-compose.yml` replacing `HOST_BRIDGE_IP` with it's ip in docker bridge:

```
HOST_BRIDGE_IP=$(docker network inspect bridge \
  --format '{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}') \
&& sed -e "s/HOST_BRIDGE_IP/${HOST_BRIDGE_IP}/g" \
docker-compose.yml | docker-compose --file - up
```

This would allow virtual host resolution based on DNS in your server.

**Edit: This seems a bit overkill to me, anyone has a better suggestion?**

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not routing directly to the host's network. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container#31328031) may help.