# Docker access localhost port from container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container running a Nuxt.js (Vue.js) app, defined by `docker_composes.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  vue:
    build: .
    image: registry.gitlab.com/something/app:${TAG}
    environment:
      - apiPath="http://localhost:5000/"
      - filePath="http://localhost:3000/"
    ports:
     - "${EXPOSED_PORT:-80}:${NUXT_PORT:-3000}"
    restart: always
```

The app is a frontend. I am running the backend on localhost, on port `5000`.
When the containerized app tries to connect to `http://localhost:5000/` it fails.

What are my options?
I don't want to put the backend into the `docker_composes.yml` and connect them by link. If it's the only option though, I will.

Comment: Did you find the solution for it?

Answer (score 87):

`localhost` in your `docker-compose.yaml` file refers to container.

In order to access your local machine use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Or run on the host network rather than the default bridge.

Comment: I have tried above, but same error, unable to connect localhost, it refuses my system network `http://host.docker.internal:8042/changes?`

Comment: I searched for this setting for _far too long_. thank you.

Comment: @151291 did you ever find a solution to your problem? If you're running Linux this might be why: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264

Comment: Don't be fooled if `http://host.docker.internal` does not available from the browser. You can still see it from within the running dockerized application.

Comment: Note that the DNS alias `host.docker.internal` is a feature of **Docker Desktop for Windows**. See also https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host.

Comment: On Linux: if you have mapped your host localhost like: `docker run --rm -it --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway alpine sh` and it is still unable to connect, then your host application is probably only binding to `127.0.0.1` whereas it should bind to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @zingi im using docker on Ubuntu WSL and I still couldnt manage to make it work even after binding my spring boot app to `0.0.0.0` via the property `server.address`

Answer (score 11):

if you want to access the host's localhost you can use the IP address of your host. in Linux use ifconfig command to get your IP address.
Eg: if your host IP is 192.168.1.7 you can use 192.168.1.7:5000

Comment: This is helpful if you're not managing your container, for example running an AWS Lambda function locally.  Much easier to change local IP in a config file for local dev than start interfering with the container.

Answer (score 8):

You could try using

network_mode: "host"

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

If you're on Windows or Mac you should be able to use:

docker.for.win.localhost
or
docker.for.mac.localhost

Comment: I tried network_mode: "host", it didn't work. The container couldn't talk to my localhost:5000 port.

Comment: @euphe check if the service is running on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost

Answer (score 5):

One way in which containers can communicate with one another is when they are attached to a common network. They can refer to each other using the container name. Example frontend can reach backend using `backend:5000` where backend is the name the backend container.

To acheive this, create a docker network using `docker network create app-network`. Attach the backend container to this network using `docker container attach <backend-container> app-network`. Finally, update the compose file to the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  vue:
    build: .
    image: registry.gitlab.com/something/app:${TAG}
    environment:
      - apiPath="http://backend:5000/" # replace backend-container name
      - filePath="http://localhost:3000/"
    ports:
     - "${EXPOSED_PORT:-80}:${NUXT_PORT:-3000}"
    restart: always
    networks:
     - app-network

networks:    
  app-network:
    external: true
```

Comment: I will try it. What if backend is not a container, can I just specify an IP address? Can backend be localhost (the host running the docker-composes)?

Comment: @Euphe If the backend is not running in a container rather is running on the host machine, you need to connect to the host. Note that localhost from the perspective of the container is not the host machine. There several ways to connect to the host machine from with the container. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container