# Selenium refuse to connect if tested application run on port other than 80

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium server. Its working well to test an application running on port 80.

but if I test an application running on another port than 80, e.g. 5001, the connection is refused.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities;        
br = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
br.get("http://127.0.0.1:5001/login/")
br.get_screenshot_as_file("/tmp/test.png")
```

I get the following screenshot:
[image]

How can I test on port 5001 ?

*EDIT*

I am running Selenium server as a Docker container with docker-compose:

```
version: '2'

services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
```

Comment: does it work if you launch browser manually?

Comment: Can you please shortly describe the web server you're trying to reach? Does it work with port 5001 manually? Have your tried https?

Comment: The application works when I open it on Chrome. It's a Flask application running on localhost:5001. It does not work with https.

Comment: Just a suggestion: try 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.  Also is there a way to confirm that your service is running on port 5001?  When I connect with Appium server, for example, I can specify a different port than the default of 4723, but the server, of course, needs to be configured to run on the port specified.

Comment: Yes I can connect to the application through Chrome by using "http://127.0.01:5001". Selenium is running on port 4444 which is fine.

Comment: Sounds like you should open a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

You are running Selenium inside a Docker container. If you try to connect to localhost, that points to the Docker container itself.

You have to connect to your host like it is described here: [How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container)

> Use your internal IP address or connect to the special DNS name `host.docker.internal` which will resolve to the internal IP address used by the host.