# Docker compose api cannot connect to host MongoDB database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localhost

I've moved my Mongodb from a container to a local service (it was really flaky when containerised). Problem is I cannot connect from a Node api into the locally running MongoDB service. I can get this working on my Mac, but not on Ubuntu. I've tried:

```
 - DB_HOST=mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/proto?authSource=admin

 - DB_HOST=mongodb://localhost:27017/proto?authSource=admin

 // this works locally, but not on my Ubuntu server
 - DB_HOST=mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/proto?authSource=admin
```

Tried adding this to my docker file:

```
  ip -4 route list match 0/0 | awk '{print $3 "host.docker.internal"}' >> /etc/hosts && \
```

Also tried network bridge to no avail. Example docker compose

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  search-api:
    build: ../search-api
    environment:
      - PORT=3333
      - DB_HOST=mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/search?authSource=admin
      - DB_USER=dbuser
      - DB_PASS=password
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    restart: always
```

Comment: host.docker.internal only works on Mac only. Not on any Linux including Ubuntu. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-macos

Comment: I got this working. Error was Mongodb was not set to listen on the correct ip address. Fixed that and could then connect.

Answer (score 2):

Problem can be caused by MongoDb not listening on the correct [ip address](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) and therefore blocking your access.

Either make sure you're listening to a specific ip or listening to all: `0.0.0.0`
On linux the config file is per default installed here: `/etc/mongod.conf`

Configuration specific Ip address:

```
net:
    bindIp: 172.17.0.1 #being your host's ip address
    port: 27017
```

Configuration open to all connections:

```
net:
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
    port: 27017
```

To get your hosts ip address (from within a container) 
On docker-for-mac and docker-for-windows you can use `host.docker.internal`
While on linux you need to run `ip route show` in the container.

> When running Docker natively on Linux, you can access host services using the IP address of the `docker0` interface.  From inside the container, this will be your default route.
>
> For example, on my system:
>
> ```
> $ ip addr show docker0
> 7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
>     link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>     inet6 fe80::f4d2:49ff:fedd:28a0/64 scope link 
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
> ```
>
> And inside a container:
>
> ```
> # ip route show
> default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 
> 172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0  src 172.17.0.4
> ```

(copied from here:  [How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container))