# macOS Ventura and Docker net=host using Rancher Desktop

Tags: docker, macos, networking, rancher-desktop

I want to run Docker containers on my Macbook running Ventura and Rancher Desktop. The services - DNS - should be exposed inside my private LAN and I would like to use `net=host`.

As far as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555007/docker-mac-alternative-to-net-host) Docker Desktop did not allow `net=host`. Can I use it with Rancher Desktop? If not what is a workaround?