# GCP instance returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for Ajax 127.0.0.1 route

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-cloud-platform, bokeh

I have a flask application using [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) that is running in a Docker container, and it works when I use it on local machines.

However, when I deploy it to a GCP instance, even though I can reach the server, I have some AjaxDataSource() objects which are failing to connect.

Some details,

- All the machines, local and gcp vm are running Ubuntu 18.04
- The flask app is started like this,

  `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=6600, debug=False)`
- The Ajax route looks like this,

  `http://127.0.0.1:6600/land/tmidemo/data_rate?name=ResultBaseKeysV1`
- The GCP firewall rules look like,

  ```
  Name                Type    Targets         Filters                 Protocols / ports       Action  Priority    Network
  tmiserver-egress    Egress  Apply to all    IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0    tcp:6600    udp:6600    Allow   1000        default
  tmiserver-ingress   Ingress Apply to all    IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0    tcp:6600    udp:6600    Allow   1000        default
  ```
- The docker container is run like this,

  ```
  docker run --net tminet --hostname=TEST -p 6600:6600 -v $(pwd):/app/public --name myserver --rm myserver
  ```
- I am not using a Bokeh server.  The AjaxDataSource() calls point back to the flask application, not another (bokeh) server

There is a lot that works,

- able to use the GCP external ip address and reach the server
- going from web page to web page works, so flask routing is working

Whats *NOT* working is that Ajax() call which uses `127.0.0.1`, although this DOES work when I run the container on a local machine.

The error I see in the inspect window is **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

The GCP instance `hosts.conf` *DOES* include a line for `127.0.0.1 localhost`

I tried (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981)) on the GCP VM instance, same result,

```
    iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

I also tried (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981)) changing the Docker run network to `--net="host"` and the result is identical.

I also tried adding `--add-host localhost:127.0.0.1` to the Docker run command, same result.

I think the problem is configuring the GCP to know how to route a request to `127.0.0.1`, but I don't know where to check, configure this, beyond what I have already done.

Comment: What is your command for starting Bokeh server? Do you use the **--allow-websocket-origin IP_ADDRESS** to white-list the IP_ADDRESS from which you access the Bokeh server?

Comment: Shouldn't your Ajax calls target your VM's external IP instead of localhost?

Comment: @tony I am not using a Bokeh server.

Comment: @LundinCast That might work, and I plan to test that as an experiment.  Using the VM's external IP address is not a good idea because that IP address is not static.  Using localhost (127.0.0.1) should work for any deployment, and it does on physical machines, just not on GCP VM.

Comment: Docker internal port mapping is dynamic but on your host machine you can use this approach to get all the info that you need: 1) In you "Docker run command" name your Docker container explicitly using ''**--name=YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME**'' 2)  Use ''**docker port  YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME**'' to show port mapping

Comment: @tony $ docker port tmiserver
6600/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:6600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to specifically resolve the issue I was having, but I tried a different approach to the URL for the `AjaxDataSource()` and it worked and I think a better approach...

I used Flask `url_for()` function to create a link to the route that the `AjaxDataSource()` needs and this worked.  The resulting link looks something like,

```
    /land/tmidemo/data_rate/ResultBaseKeysV1
```

ie, no `http://127.0.0.1`, and this seems to work in all cases, my dev environment and GCP.

I think I tried this a long time ago and it didn't work, because I use "flask" URLs all over the place, but for some reason I thought I needed "http://127.0.0.1" for the Ajax stuff.  Its works now.... moving on!