# How to configure spring-boot microservice docker container to access local mongodb database?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, microservices

I have a microservice developed with spring boot that connects with a mongodb.
When a run it local, everything is ok.
When I create a docker container to my microservice, but NOT to my mongodb, I receive an error of "connection refused".
I was connecting to my mongodb at "localhost:27017", and then "127.0.0.1:27017", but both doesn't work. I know that the problem is this address because docker uses a network adapter different from the server, but I can't find how to configure to my spring boot container connects with my mongodb local.
Is this approach wrong?
I don't wanna to dockerize my mongodb because in the future the application will not be together with my database.

I'm using a Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Use your real IP address instead. Localhost addresses will resolve to the container itself.

Comment: Thanks Paulo! In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container) link, I found my answer!

Comment: Thank you for pointing the answer. It's very thorough. I mainly use Docker in the development stages and using the host IP address also works, but the pointed solution is far more independent.

Comment: Yes, I liked the pointed solution too!