# Failing consul health check on local machine

Tags: docker, consul, service-discovery

I have Consul running via docker using docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:  
  consul:
    image: unifio/consul:latest
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8300:8300"
    volumes: 
      - ./config:/config
      - ./.data/consul:/data
    command: agent -server -data-dir=/data -ui -bind 0.0.0.0 -client 0.0.0.0 -bootstrap-expect=1
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
      - "27018:27018"
    volumes:
      - ./.data/mongodb:/data/db
    command: mongod --bind_ip_all
```

and have a nodejs service running on port `6001` which exposes a `/health` endpoint for health checks.
I am able to register the service via this [consul package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consul).
However, visiting the consul UI I can see that the service has a status of `failing` because the health check is not working.

The UI show this message:

```
Get http://127.0.0.1:6001/health: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6001: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Not sure why is not working exactly, but I kind of sense that i may have misconfigured consul.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this issue @MrFoh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consul is running in your docker container. When you use 127.0.0.1 in this container, it refers to itself, not to your host.

You need to use a host IP that is known to your container (and of course make sure your service is reachable and listening on this particular IP).

In most cases, you should be able to contact your host from a container through the default `docker0` bridge ip that you can get with `ip addr show dev docker0` from your host as outlined [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328031/9401096).

The best solution IMO is to discover the gateway that your container is using which will point to the particular bridge IP on your host (i.e. the bridge created for your docker-compose project when starting it). There are [several methods you can use](https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-find-default-gateway-in-linux/) to discover this ip from the container depending on the installed tooling and your linux flavor.

Answer (score 3):

While Zeitounator's answer is perfectly fine and answers your direct question,
the "indirect" solution to your problem would be to manage the nodejs service 
through docker-compose.

IMHO it's a good idea to manage all services involved using the same tool,
as then their lifecycles are aligned and also it's easy to configure them to talk
to each other (at least that's the case for `docker-compose`).

Moreover, letting containers access services on the host is risky in terms of security.
In production environments you usually want to shield host services from containers,
as otherwise the containers lose their "containment" role.

So, in your case you would need to add the nodejs service to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  (...)
  nodejs-service:
    image: nodejs-service-image
    ports:
    - "6001:6001" [this is only required if you need to expose the port on the host]
    command: nodejs service.js
```

And then your Consul service would be able to access `nodejs-service`
through `http://nodejs-service:6001/health`.