# Reach host machine from docker container on specific port

Tags: docker, networking

I'm runing my docker container with network host. I can ping my localhost with the `ping localhost` command in the container and everything is fine. But I can't reach **localhost:8000**. Is there a way that I can reach localhost on specific port from docker container?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have an API on my host machine that is runing on port 8000. When I try to curl from my docker container to that api, I can't. This is why I changed my connection from bridge to host.

After I did that I was able to ping localhost (not sure which localhost) but I'm assuming it was the host machine. Curl returns me this error.

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect
> to localhost port 8000: Connection refused (see
> https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in file
> /var/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line
> 200

When I try to tellnet localhost It doesn't work aswell. (can't resolve host or something like that). I'm doing everything from inside of the docker container as root.

My docker container is build on the following image `php:7.2-apache`

I set my connection back to bridnge and used the `host.docker.internal` host that is in the documentation but there was no success. I can still ping from my container `host.docker.internal` and get a response

> PING host.docker.internal (192.168.65.2) 56(84) bytes of data. 64
> bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=37 time=0.771
> ms 64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=37
> time=1.20 ms 64 bytes from 192.168.65.2 (192.168.65.2): icmp_seq=3
> ttl=37 time=0.548 ms

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect
> to host.docker.internal port 8000: Connection refused (see
> https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in file
> /var/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line
> 200

I started my laravel api with `php artisan serve` using the following parameters
`php artisan serve --host=host.docker.internal --port=8000`

I can access it from my browser

> Laravel development server started on
> http://host.docker.internal:8000/ [Thu Jul 23 10:00:24 2020]
> 192.168.x.x:60126 [200]: /favicon.ico

But the docker container still can't access the server from the container.

Lastly I tried to access http://host.docker.internal with curl and it worked fine. The problem is in the port. Could it be firewall or something that is blocking it? I listed the 8000 port in my Windows on inbound rules for public, private and domain networks with TCP connections but that did not work aswell.
I'm confused.

I turned the firewall off there is no success still

**Problem solved**

When I was doing the curl request I was trying to reach a port in the following way:
`host.docker.internal:8000` - This was my curl URL leading to connectiong refused.

After that I check Guzzle if I can set somehow a port without specifing it in the url.

So I found [this](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/http-messages.html#port) in the docs. I used that to specify my port *8000* and ran my artisan server with the following command

`php artisan serve --host=host.docker.internal --port=8000`

also I set my `APP_URL` to `APP_URL=http://host.docker.internal/`

From there on everything worked like a charm.

Comment: You can use special DNS if you are on mac or window `host.docker.internal:8000` or use host ip if on Linux

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what's going wrong?  Why are you disabling Docker's networking?  Which `localhost` are you trying to reach?

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes sorry. I will edit my post

Answer (score 4):

Look at this question [How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container)

if you are using linux  the argument `--net="host"` will work

Comment: tested it works in my debian (via wsl)

Comment: Nice and simple! Not something you normally see with the minefield that is Docker. Great!