# How would I connect to a MySQL on the host machine from inside a docker kubernetes pod?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kind

I have a MySQL server running on my local machine, accessible at `localhost:3306`.

I also have a KinD cluster set up on WSL2, with Docker integration. How would I access the server from a python application inside a kubernetes pod?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31324981/5221149)

Comment: Yes, thanks. `host.docker.internal` worked from inside the pod