# How to network between Docker images at build time?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

I have a project `sample` with two services, `database` and `app`, declared in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  database:
    image: sample/database
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: database.Dockerfile
      network: sample_default

    ports:
    - "8001:5432"

  app:
    image: sample/app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app.Dockerfile
      network: sample_default
      args:
        - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@database:5432/cluster

    depends_on:
      - database

networks:
  sample_default: {}
```

`database.Dockerfile` takes care of downloading and installing Postgre, as well as starting a Postgre cluster and database within that cluster. The tables of this database are created through `CREATE TABLE` at build time under a `RUN` command.

`app.Dockerfile` takes care of downloading and installing the compiler, as well as compiling the source code.

In order for `app.Dockerfile`'s image to be built, `database.Dockerfile`'s image must be built first. This is because, at compile time, SQL query strings within the source code are validated against the database created in `database.Dockerfile`.

The compiler uses `DATABASE_URL` to connect to the Postgre database which contains the tables to validate the queries against. Within this `DATABASE_URL`, the specified address is `database:5432`, since service discovery can be used on non-default bridge networks.

My problem is that in running `docker-compose up`, `app` at build time cannot connect to `database` at build time. A `RUN ping database` in `app.Dockerfile` fails with `ping: database: No address associated with hostname`. Yet, starting a container from both images on the `sample_default` network (manually instead of through `docker-compose`) and running `ping database` from `app`'s container is successful.

I have already specified the `network` under `build` in `docker-compose.yml`, so what can I do on top of that to allow build-time networking here?

Comment: Just an idea, you should try and see if it works: You could use docker-in-docker and then, inside, create services containers and build container in a similar way as gitlag does. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-docker-integration-works

Comment: if I understood this correctly, it is an wait issue. App needs to wait for the database to build because running? Am I correct? Is there connection retry? I never seen the usage of 'network' property, I have seen 'Networks'. Is this correct? The service will be added to a default network if now networks are specified.

Comment: @mr.vea Yeah, app needs to wait for database to build because app compiler depends on database. I think you're right about the default network, but my challenge is using this at docker image build time instead of run time.

Comment: have you tried multistage build dockerfile? https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Answer (score 1):

In the build-time, there is no network configuration comes up. Because Docker container is like VM. you can't connect to VM in its boot time via it's IP address. docker container also the same. The only differents is container fast booting process than the VM; therefore, you need to wait until it comes up. After booting up a container, it's life cycle is the runtime.

Comment: I'm looking at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options and I see that `--network` lets me "Set the networking mode for the RUN instructions during build". That's why I thought networking could be done during build, what is this referring to instead?

Comment: You can attach network configuration during the build time, but you have to wait until it became runtime to access via your network configuration done by build time.

Answer (score 0):

Add depends_on section in your yml file.
eg.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  database:
    image: sample/database
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: database.Dockerfile
      network: sample_default

    ports:
    - "8001:5432"

  app:
    image: sample/app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app.Dockerfile
      network: sample_default
      args:
        - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@database:5432/cluster
      depends_on:
        - database

networks:
  sample_default: {}
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to copy the `depends_on` from my actual docker compose file. Edited to include `depends_on` in the question, issue still persists with it.

Comment: remove  ```network: sample_default``` from docker-compose file and try . by default it will create its own network.

Answer (score 0):

As I already see that you use depends_on, it is already a good start ;)

Following is a working docker-compose.yml for one of my other project, in a different docker-compose version, I suggest:

- you may need a [custom network bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)
- where you can assign custom ip address to every image
- and [subnet with a valid CIDR](https://runnable.com/docker/docker-compose-networking)

I needed my db connection set up, so that I can run protractor ui-test inside the docker network against the mongo db through my server, consequently, I also need to have health check for a specific port on my server. UI-test will restart on failure, if it did not succeed.

```
version: "3" # docker-compose version: 1.21.1 for version 3 misleading I know: check out https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2017/03/28/comparing-docker-compose-versions/
services:
  server:
    build: server # frontend code stored as static files in node server
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "8443:8443"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.17.1.3
    healthcheck:
      # test: ["CMD", "curl", "-k", "https://localhost:8443"]
      # test: ifconfig
      test: curl -k http://192.17.1.3:8443
      # test: curl http://localhost:8443/bundle.js -k -s | grep -C 3 "window.pushNotification"
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
  mongo:
    image: mongo # pulling on docker-compose up if image not available
    #    volumes: # TODO mongo2.6
    #      - /Users/yuqiuge/Downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.10/data/db:/data/db
    #      - /data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      app_net:
        # static different ip for mongo
        ipv4_address: 192.17.1.2
  protractor:
    build: webapp
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - server
    links:
      - server
    networks:
      app_net:
        # static different ip for ui test on webapp
        ipv4_address: 192.17.1.4

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.17.1.0/24
```