# Redis connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, redis, containers

Im running redis on my server (Redis is not running in a container)  and I am trying to connect to redis inside of my Container which has a Node.js app runninng. When starting the Docker Container with the node app from my Dockerfile in the logs there is the following error: `Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` means port `6379` already is in use

Comment: Yes it is used by Redis on the server when I do redis-cli ping on the server it answers with pong. So the redis-server works but in the node app in my docker container i cant connect

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Docker now provides a custom DNS-name called `host.docker.internal` for Windows/Mac versions (see https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds) which resolves to the internal IP address of the host.

So instead of using `localhost:6379`/`127.0.0.1:6379` in your connection string, change it to `host.docker.internal:6379`.

Note: for Linux there's a workaround -> see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61424570/3761628