# Access service in host networking mode from another service in the same stack

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm running two services in a single-node Docker Swarm, both in the same stack. Service **A** needs to be in host networking mode in order to use the ipv6 tunnel configured on the host machine, and service **B** needs to talk to service **A**.

Back when **A** didn't need to use the host networking mode, **B** was able to reach **A** by using the service name as the hostname, but it doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

I've tried to use `docker0` as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container), without any success.

How can I reach that host-networked service from another service in the same stack?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible in Swarm mode.  If A is using host networking then it will only be accessible via its host's IP address or DNS name, not using any Docker-internal networking mechanics, but in Swarm mode I don't think it's easy to predict which node the container will be on.

Comment: @DavidMaze we run a single-node swarm, so it should be fine. I really just need a way to loopback to the host's IP from inside a container, I guess.