# How to fix auth error on CouchDB replication

Tags: couchdb, replication

I've setup local/remote CouchDB servers and I'd like to replicate between them.

Curling on each works fine so I know both databases are running ok:

`curl -u admin:password https://remote.host.net/db_name` - works

`curl -u admin:password http://localhost:5984/db_name` - works

However, when I try and setup replication it borks. This is the command used to setup the replication:

```
curl -u admin:password -X POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -d '{"source":"https://admin:password@remote.host.net/db_name", "target":"http://admin:password@localhost:5984/db_name"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Error message:

```
{"error":"replication_auth_error","reason":"{session_request_failed,\"https://remote.host.net/_session\",\n\"admin\",\n{conn_failed,{error,nxdomain}}}"}
```

Anyone have any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: I had a similar problem, which was due to my local instance being run within a docker container that was not allowed access to the remote host

Comment: Thanks, @maxlath. I changed the hostname of the target database from `localhost` to  `host.docker.internal` and it seems to be working now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541732.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and adding `"continuous": true` to the request body, returns with a `"ok":true`.

From the docs, `continuous` should be used only when you want the replication to be triggered always the source changes, I don't know why the error when it is not included.

[edit]

Even with the success response, the data is not been copied. So we use this script to achieve the replication https://gist.github.com/Aybee5/fba07b06b94442a529ebae5465b77737

Answer (score 0):

Yup.. I know its been almost a year since I posted the original question but I just ran into a similar issue and solved it by using the `source_proxy`/`target_proxy` kwargs in the replication request.

I can't remember if I was behind a proxy last time unfortunately.