# docker-compose connection between containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have 3 containers with my bot, server and db. after docker-compose up, server and db are working. telegram bot does get-request and takes this error:
Get "http://localhost:8080/user/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: todo_postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      # TODO: Change it to environment variables
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB: somedb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
  server:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      DB_NAME: somedb
      DB_USERNAME: user
      DB_PASSWORD: pass

  bot:
    depends_on:
      - server
    build:
      ./src/telegram_bot
    environment:
      BOT_TOKEN: TOKEN
    restart: always
    links:
      - server
```

Comment: All we can tell from this is that apparently there is no process listening on localhost:8080. Consider providing a little more information about the bot docker image to help you, as how it is configured or if you are using any library or framework to develop the bot. Also, using `depends_on` and `links` options seem redundant.

Comment: `localhost` in Docker almost always means "this container"; [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes how to connect to other containers.  You shouldn't need `links:` at all in modern Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using compose, try using the containers hostname.. in the case your bot should try to connect to

server:8080

Compose will handle the name resolution to the IP you need

Answer (score 3):

What you try is to access localhost within your container (service) `bot`.

Maybe [this answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container) will help you to solve the problem. It sound similar to your problem.

---

But I want to provide you another solution to your problem:

In case it's not needed to access the containers form outside (from your host), one appraoch would be making use of the `expose` functionality and a docker network.

- See [docs.docker.com: network](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

The `expose` functionality allows to access your other containers within your network

- See [docs.docker.com: expose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose)

> Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine - they’ll only be accessible to linked services. Only the internal port can be specified.

---

### Example

What is this example doing?

A couple of steps that are **not mandatory**

1. Set a *static ip* within your docker container
   *These Steps are not needed and can be omitted*. However, I like to do this, since you have now a better control over the network. **You can access the containers by their hostname (which is the container name or service name) as well**.

The steps that are needed are the following:

2. This exposes port 8080, but do not publish it.

   ```
   expose:
         - 8080
   ```
3. The network which allows static ip configuration

   ```
   networks:
     vpcbr:
       driver: bridge
       ipam:
         config:
           - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
   ```

A complete file could look similar to this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  first-service:
    image: <your-image>
    networks: 
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.2
    expose:
      - 8080

  second-service:
     image: <your-image>
    networks: 
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.3
    depends_on: 
      - first-service

networks:
  vpcbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `bot` container is up **before** your server & db containers.
When you use `depends_on` it's **not** accually waiting them to finish setup themeselves.
You should try some tricky algorithem for waiting the other container finish setup.
I remmember that when I used Nginx proxy I used something called [`wait-for-it.sh`](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)