# How do I set up docker containters to refer to each other by host name?

Tags: docker, development-environment

I have 2 docker containers (1 for database and 1 for app server). The app code has the host of the database in the connection string. I would like to be able to run the app without modifying any code (including connection string / host configuration).

My thought was to add something to the /etc/hosts file on the app container so the database host resolves to the other container but not sure what IP address I could set. The IP could be different every time I create the containers right? The below works sort of but I need something more permanent.

```
172.23.0.2    database.mycompany.com
```

would be cool if I could specify something like this in /etc/hosts

```
db-container-name  database.mycompany.com
```

Edit: Lots of very helpful comments but the one thing being missed is I have a connection string in the codebase and I dont want to change the code:

```
<New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
   <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@db.mycompany.com:1532:SVC</Set>
</New>
```

If I want to use container name I would have to change the above config to the container name. Ive tested and it works but I cant check that in ever so I need something that doesnt change the code. The static IP address option mentioned below is probably my best bet and will confirm that answer once I can test it out.

Comment: We should rather refactor the code, conforming to the [twelve factors](https://12factor.net/). In particular, we should externalize the resources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose connection between containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65042615/docker-compose-connection-between-containers)

Comment: Thanks Noam. I originally was thinking something similar the problem is I would still have to change the codebase which Im avoiding at all costs and this would require me to update the connection string. Hence I did get the idea to change my container name to match the database host name as a workaround.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site for programming questions; the [help/on-topic] describes what is allowed here.  If changing code is out of scope, what is your programming-related question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample docker-compose.yml.

Check the static IP assignment below:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx: <- DNS Name
    image: nginx
    container_name: qs
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ~/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - server01
    networks:
      nginx:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.1.10 <- Static IP

networks:
  nginx:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.1.1.0/24 <- Static IP subnet
```

By this you can eliminate the problem of dynamic IP

You can create multiple networks and assign as per you connection requirements.

```
networks:
  nginx:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.1.1.0/24
  db:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/24
```

Like here you can see that there are 2 networks,
How I use this is my app container and nginx are on nginx network and my db and app are on db network. so my db is accessed by my customers only by accessing my app via nginx. And there is no need to open port to host for db because container-to-container connection require no port opening.

Comment: ok will check that option as well

Comment: this seems like a good option and will probably try to run with it. One follow up question though. Ive realized I created the DB host on standard oracle port 1521 but the code actually references port 1532. Do you know if its possible to have port mappings between containers on same network like 1532:1521? Im just being lazy and can go update the port on the database host to 1532 if called for.

Comment: thanks - works great! Your solution is better than my workaround below because it gives developers who will be using the docker images the option to modify the host file and point back at our real database if needed. Changing the container name to match the db host makes that more difficult.

Comment: @George for the port mapping case, do it like 1532:1521 will not work because 1532 port will be accessed from you local host and not the docker network. Inside docker network it will always be accessible by port 1521 only.




You do not need to open port if you are not going to connect to it remotely outside the docker network

Answer (score 1):

ok so I figured out a workaround. I can call my container database.mycompany.com since docker automatically creates dns mappings for each container name. Since the code references database.mycompany.com already everything works without a code change.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the containers in the same network and call each container with name from the others.

creating a network:

```
docker network create my-network
```

run first container:

```
docker run --name mydb -d --expose <some_port> --network=my-network mydbimage
```

run second container which will connect:

```
docker run --name myserver -d -e DB_HOST=mydb --network=my-network myserverimage
```

for this example you can use DB_HOST environment for connecting