# could not translate host name to "db" to address: Unknown host

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm attempting to follow the guide provided by: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/
Whenever I attempt to makemigrations, it gives me the Unknown host error given in the title. I'm trying to use PostgreSQL with Django and Wagtail as its CMS

My docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and my settings in the settings.py file look like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: How are you running the makemigrations command?

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: You should run the management commands from the web container. Try `docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: Thank you! That didn't give me an error. However, now I have wagtailcore.site does not exist? Should I make a new question regarding this?

Comment: Happy to help. Sounds like a separate issue, a new question is probably appropriate

Comment: I was just blanking out, I quickly realized I didn't migrate, thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can run in two different environments, and hard-coding the connection information might not be correct.

You mention in a comment that you're running something like:

```sh
docker-compose up -d db
python manage.py makemigrations
```

In this environment `python` is running outside of Docker.  If you add `ports: [5432:5432]` to the database configuration in the `docker-compose.yml` file, the database will be accessible via (probably) `localhost`.  On the other hand, when you run `docker-compose up`, the application runs inside Docker and the database will be reachable at `db`.

You can use an environment variable to configure this.  I find it useful to give these variables default values that would be useful for a developer, and set them to different values in my deployment setup (the `docker-compose.yml`).

```python
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        ...
    }
}
```

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - '5432:5432' # makes this accessible from your development environment
    ...
  web:
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In my situation both `db` and `localhost` did not work. So I set `settings.py` to:

```py
DATABASES = { 
        "default": {
         ...
        'HOST': 'host.docker.internal',
        ...

    }
}
```

Which allows one docker container to access all other containers similar to localhost. Source of idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62147846/7924573