# How to connect External mysql DB to Docker Web Container

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, containers

I am trying to access the MySQL database in the Docker container but is not allowing me to access it.

The Mysql database is running on my local machine.

I tried with **docker run --network="127.0.0.1"  -it -p 8080:8080** but no luck

my docker file

```
FROM tomcat:latest
ADD target/sample.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Comment: Could you check if this answer works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541732/1336841

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links) you have two options, to use links, or using networks.
AFAIK you are using flag --network in the wrong way

Answer (score 1):

In your container, to connect to host machine, you will use `host.docker.internal`.

In your case it'll be `host.docker.internal:3306` (mysql)

Comment: not working for me, i also tried setting MySQL bind-address = 0.0.0.0 and   docker run --network=host -h 127.0.0.1 b0fbd48de7d7      but same issue