# Docker containers with bridge network cannot ping anything (even default gateway)

Tags: docker, networking, iptables, archlinux

I cannot ping anything from containers using bridge networking (example: `docker run --network bridge --rm -it bash ping 8.8.8.8`). Not even the default gateway of the container.

`ip route` from inside container:

```
bash-5.1# ip route
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link  src 172.17.0.2
```

`ip link` from my machine:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:02:e0:77:5a:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp16s0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:97:b1:86:f9:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:bd:d0:fb:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: veth40b832a@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether ba:e5:3a:88:e4:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

The `docker0` interface stays down even if containers are running.

`brctl` shows that the container interfaces don't get bridged to `docker0`:

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.0242bdd0fbcc   no
```

Here's the output of `iptables -S -t nat`:

```
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
```

So far I've tried reinstalling docker and switching between `iptables` and `nftables` with `iptables-nft`. The whole issue started when I tried running a `k3d` example cluster. I'm running everything on Arch using the official packages.

Comment: GENERAL IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out

Both NetworkManager and systemd-networkd were running on my system, which messed with the interface IPs via multiple DHCP services. That caused bridge networking not to work as well, which in turn messed with the containers traffic.

Pro tip: don't run multiple daemons trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Check
cat /etc/sysctl.conf
if you have 
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Comment: I don't have that file. Checked with `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` and its set to 1: `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container

Comment: Tried a couple of things from the link. The IP assigned to `docker0` is `172.17.0.1`. I can ping it from my maching, but not from within containers, even though it's their default gateway. I also tried adding the `iptables` rule `iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT`. Still same situation

Comment: ? https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248/5

Answer (score 0):

Check your docker-desktop networks, there should be a conflict that trying to reach out ip address. For example lets say you are connected 192.168.1.1 on your host and you have 192.168.0.0/20 docker network (disabled or enabled), then you cant ping 192.168.1.x from any docker container. Delete unused docker network which is trying to ping subnet.