# Connection refused when running flyway in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, flyway

I'm trying to run flyway from docker following the official [repository](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-docker). When running the folowing cmd:

```
docker run flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flyway_demo_db -user=* -password=* info
```

I installed flyway cmd-tool on my machine and ran a similar cmd:

```
flyway -url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flyway_demo_db -user=* -password=* info
```

This works fine. I'm unsure what's causing this since `-password` is a valid argument.  My machine is running on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing an cmd argument for the docker run command `--net="host"`

Example that works:

```
docker run --net="host" flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flyway_demo_db -user=* -password=* info
```

Source: [How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container/43541732#43541732)