# How to connect OSX host port from docker container?

Tags: macos, docker, web3py

I have private ethereum running node on my OSX at `http://localhost:8545`
From the OSX I can connect to this node

```py
In [1]:         from web3 import Web3
   ...:         w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
   ...:         w3.isConnected()
   ...:
Out[1]: True
```

Then I run my docker container with the same command by using special DNS name [`host.docker.internal`](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/)

```py
In [2]:         from web3 import Web3
   ...:         w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://host.docker.internal:8545'))
   ...:         w3.isConnected()
   ...:
Out[2]: False
```

```sh
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    network_mode: host
```

`network_mode: host` does support only [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866007/1019455)

`~/.docker/daemon.json`. I have different default address pools because of local DNS.

```sh
{
    "experimental":true,
    "features":{
        "buildkit":true
    },
    "builder":{
        "gc":{
            "defaultKeepStorage":"20GB",
            "enabled":true
        }
    },
  "default-address-pools":
  [
    {"base":"10.10.0.0/16","size":24}
  ]
}
```

**Question:**
How to connect OSX host port from docker container?

Comment: what is the error message? @joe

Comment: It has no error message. It just return False

Comment: `network_mode: host` will break the `host.docker.internal` host name, and just generally doesn't work on MacOS (and isn't great practice on native-Linux either).