# Connection Refused from Request Inside Docker Compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, deployment

I have an API running on my host machine on port 8000. Meanwhile, I have a docker compose cluster with one container that's supposed to connect said API. To get the url for the request, I use "host.docker.internal:8000" on my windows machine and it works wonderfully. However, I have a linux deployment server and in there, "host.docker.internal" doesn't resolve to anything, causing a connection error to the API. I saw on another [post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container/61424570#61424570), that you solve this on linux by adding the following on your `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
services:
  service_name:
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

This added the docker0 IP to `/etc/hosts`, but when I try to do a GET request, the resulting message is:

`Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 8000: Connection refused`

I'm really confused right now. I don't know if this is a firewall issue, a docker issue, a docker compose issue, a docker on linux issue. Please help...

Comment: Make sure your API binds to 0.0.0.0 and not to localhost. If it binds to localhost, it won't accept connections from containers.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. I just changed the API binding and everything started working.

Comment: @Eddysanoli it would be nice to know what exactly did you do to get it work.

Comment: So previously my API was listening for requests on localhost. After changing the API so that it listens on 0.0.0.0, everything worked with the setup described above.

Comment: @cheack I tried this by, for my project, which is a sort of wsgi python server, changing the hosting url in a settings file somewhere from `localhost:9000` to `0.0.0.0:9000` directly, which caused my python server to run on `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`. However, I was still getting `connection refused` errors, so the solution may not work for everyone.

Comment: Oh, thats unfortunate. Sorry to hear that. Did you manage to solve it in any other way @CalebJay?

Comment: No, sorry. I'll update here if I do. We're still trying to get our application working on linux machines, something about the way docker handles networks is different on osx vs linux distros it seems.

Comment: In my case, binding to 0.0.0.0 did not fix the issue but binding to 127.0.0.1 did. Leaving this here incase it can help someone else

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Credit to @Hans Kilian:

- Add `extra_hosts` to docker-compose file
- Change URL to use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`
- Change service to serve on `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and got it working by making sure that my tunnel accepted connections from everywhere.

Before:

```
ssh -N -L 5435:endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 admin@machine.ip
```

After:

```
ssh -N -L 0.0.0.0:5435:endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 admin@machine.ip
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone encounters a similar issue, if one of your containers has a wsgi/usgi server (uvicorn, gunicorn, etc) make sure that wherever you start such web server, play around with setting any bind argument or host argument to both `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0`

for example in my fastapi server, when I did uvicorn.run, I had to pass `0.0.0.0` so other containers would be able to interact with it, passing none, or other, did not help.