# Docker container can't connect to host Linux even when using host.docker.internal as an extra-host

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, localhost, docker-network

I want to be able to host a Prometheus instance in Docker, and have that instance get the host metrics using Prometheus Node Exporter.

To connect to the host from within a container, [it should be possible to use the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host). The docs don't mention this, but apparently it is required to [set this manually via `extra_hosts`](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40007) on Linux - which I have done, but it still does not work.

#### Steps to reproduce

I first start listening on `0.0.0.0:55555` with ncat.

```bash
➜ ncat -vv -k -l -p 55555
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on :::55555
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:55555
```

I then verify that, from the host machine, I can connect to ncat successfully:

```bash
➜ telnet localhost 55555
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
```

```bash
➜ ncat -vv -k -l -p 55555
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on :::55555
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:55555
Ncat: Connection from ::1.
Ncat: Connection from ::1:48416.
```

I then start the container using Docker Compose. As you can see, I have added`host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to `extra_hosts`, [as directed this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541681/4161471).

```bash
➜ docker-compose down; docker-compose up -d; docker-compose logs -f
```

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.42.0
    user: "1000:1000"
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    extra_hosts:
      host.docker.internal: "host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - "./config/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
        # Note that Prometheus requires the mounted `data/` directory 
        # is created with fully open permissions, `chmod -R 777 data`
      - "./data/prometheus:/prometheus"
```

I then open a terminal inside the container.

```bash
➜ docker exec -it --user root prometheus /bin/sh
```

And then I try to connect to the host ncat, but I get an error.

```bash
➜ telnet host.docker.internal 55555

telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.17.0.1): Connection refused
```

I have tried the following answers, which say I should add `host.docker.internal` to `extra_hosts`, which I have done, to no effect:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73859760/4161471
- [What is linux equivalent of "host.docker.internal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-linux-equivalent-of-host-docker-internal)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541732/4161471

#### Debugging

I have tried a simpler Docker container example, [based on the Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host), but it stil fails.

```bash
➜ docker run --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway --rm -it alpine sh

# inside the container:
➜ apk add curl
➜ curl http://host.docker.internal:55555
# curl: (7) Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 55555 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I am sure that the ncat server is connectable on tcp and tcp6, and listens to `0.0.0.0`

```bash
➜ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :55555
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55555           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16150/ncat
tcp6       0      0 :::55555                :::*                    LISTEN      16150/ncat
```

When I try pinging the host from within the container, it works (or, at least it does not throw an error)

```bash
➜ ping host.docker.internal:55555
PING host.docker.internal:55555 (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.158 ms
^C
--- host.docker.internal:55555 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.049/0.103/0.158 ms
```

From within the container I can see that `/etc/hosts` has an entry for `host.docker.internal`

```bash
➜ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.1      host.docker.internal
172.17.0.2      84a18e1e361b
```

Comment: FYI, you can also host node-exporter in docker; [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/node-exporter) | [example compose file](https://gist.github.com/SIMULATAN/7c10b81712dc58307c45bec14dd937b3)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was
`iptables`
service on the host side. Whith iptables service stopped, the connection succeeded, so I just inserted a configuration on iptables to allow the connection to the docker metrics port and restarted it again.

Comment: Which configuration? It would be best if your answer explained how to reach the solution instead of just pointing the general direction.