# How do I connect to Xdebug running inside a Docker container on a remote server from my local machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, xdebug

I have a Docker Compose stack running on a cloud server. One of the services is PHP with Xdebug.

When I run the stack on my local machine, I can use Xdebug just fine. But when I run it on the remote cloud server, no matter how I configure things, I can't seem to get Xdebug to connect back to my local IDE.

I've tried changing various Xdebug settings (`discover_client_host` etc.) but nothing seems to work.

My latest attempt is as follows:

1. From `docker-compose.yml`:

```
[...]

  environment:
      - XDEBUG_MODE=debug
      - XDEBUG_CONFIG=discover_client_host=On

  ports:
      - 9003:9003

[...]

networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

2. When I run `docker compose up` on the cloud server I can see that exposes port 9003:

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep 9003
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2119936/docker-prox 
tcp6       0      0 :::9003                 :::*                    LISTEN      2119943/docker-prox
```

3. So then I try to create a port forward via an SSH tunnel from my local machine like this:

```
ssh -R 9003:localhost:9003 username@cloudhost.com
```

But I get an error: `Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 9003` presumably because port 9003 is already in use.

But if that's the case, how can I ever access port 9003 inside the Docker container from my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be quite the puzzle, and several pieces had to fit together rather precisely to solve it:

1. As per Derick's answer, I removed the `ports:` section from `docker-compose.yml`.
2. On the remote machine I had to enable `GatewayPorts clientspecified` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (then restart the sshd service).

   This allows you to create an SSH port forward tunnel which listens on all network interfaces (`0.0.0.0` or `*`) which is required in order for the Docker container's virtual network interface to reach your client machine via the tunnel. [By default](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#GatewayPorts), the `GatewayPorts` setting limits remote port forwardings to bind to the `localhost` interface only which Docker can't "see".
3. I had to change my SSH connection string to explicitly specify that I wanted to listen on the global interface `*`:

   ```
   ssh -R *:9003:localhost:9003 username@cloudhost.com
   ```

After doing all this, I was finally able to connect to Xdebug running inside a Docker container on the remote server from my local machine.

---

Optionally, if you want to explicitly force Xdebug to connect only to the host machine (meaning you only want to use Xdebug via the SSH tunnel), either:

- Add the following section to your service in `docker-compose.yml`:

  ```
       extra_hosts:
         - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
  ```

  Then set `xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal` and `xdebug.discover_client_host=Off`

or

- Set `xdebug.client_host=xdebug://gateway`

This allows the Docker container to resolve the host machine's internal IP address, as explained in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container) and [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20230714012759/https://medium.com/the-sensiolabs-tech-blog/how-to-use-xdebug-in-docker-phpstorm-76d998ef2534).

---

P.S. A useful command while debugging this was `nc -vz 127.0.0.1 9003` which allowed me to check if my SSH port forward was working on the host machine, at least.

Comment: You don't have to do your step one if you set `xdebug.client_host=xdebug://gateway`, as it will do that for you in that case.

Comment: You're right; actually I think I don't need to do either of those things because it's working with `xdebug.discover_client_host=On`. I think the main problem was just that the tunnel couldn't bind to the network interface Docker uses.

Comment: I've removed step #1 and separated it out into an optional section. Thanks @Derick

Comment: I think `discover_client_host=on` only works because it falls back to the `client_host` value if it can't connect. You really should not set it for publicly accessible web servers, as it would mean any person with an IDE on a internet-reachable address can then debug your application. You can verify what happens by using `xdebug_info()` or the log file (`xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=11` settings).

Answer (score 1):

If you set your *docker* container to expose port 9003, it will open that port. Which means that your `ssh -R` command can't open that same port.

You need to remove:

```
ports:
      - 9003:9003
```

And then your `ssh -R 9003...` command will work.

As Xdebug needs to connect *to* your machine, it also means that it needs to connect to this port `9003` that your `ssh -R` sets up. If you set `xdebug.discover_client_host=1`, then it will try to use your local machine's global IP address, which will likely not work. Instead, you need to set `xdebug.discover_client_host=0`.

The ssh tunnel that you setup basically creates (from the POV of your docker container) a port 9003 on the *host* machine. If that is already in the docker container too, then you can set `xdebug.client_host=localhost`.

I believe however, that your SSH opens a shell on the **host** where docker runs **in**. In which case you need to set `xdebug.client_host` to the IP address of it's local gateway, or, if you're using xdebug 3.2, you can set `xdebug.client_host=xdebug://gateway`.

Comment: Thank you - your answer helped but didn't quite solve things for me. There were a few more pieces of the puzzle which I'll detail in my own answer.