# Docker with Python Script trying to connect a SQL Express localhost instance

Tags: python, sql, pandas, docker, pyodbc

When i try to connect to my local SQL Server Express instance from a Python Script in my Docker container i have the next issue:

```
C:\Users\----\Proyectos_Python\Proyectos_de_Prueba\PythonSQL>docker run -it --name cont_pysql --network host -p 1433:1433 pysql
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/pythonSQL.py", line 42, in <module>
    baseinput = pyodbc.connect(conn_str_in)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sri***'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

the string i used to connect is the next:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
pyodbc.pooling = False
server = '192.***.**.**,1433' #Ethernet Ethernet adapter in ipconfig/cmd
bdconsulta = 'pruebas_seba'
tablaconsulta = 'dbo.tpruebas1'
bddestino = 'pruebas_seba2'
tabladestino = 'tpruebas2'
user='srive***'
password='******'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'conn_str_in = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={bdconsulta};UID={user};PWD={password};TrustServerCertificate=yes'
baseinput = pyodbc.connect(conn_str_in)
```

When i execute the script with Visual Studio Code everything it's ok (With user 'SRIV*****\SQLEXPRESS') but when i try to connect with my ip address that exception comes.

I hope you can help me with that, remember please, i try to connect my local machine SQL from a docker container, thanks comunity.

When i execute the script with Visual Studio Code everything it's ok (With user 'SRIV*****\SQLEXPRESS') but when i try to connect with my ip address that exception comes.

I hope you can help me with that, remember please, i try to connect my local machine SQL from a docker container, thanks comunity.

Comment: Many times this question has been asked and answered.  Here's just one of the duplicates. You can also follow the duplicate link from this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)