# "Connection refused" when using host network in Docker in GitHub Actions

Tags: java, docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, github-actions

I am starting a Docker container with Chrome inside, as follows:

```
docker run --rm --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --network=host selenoid/vnc:chrome_117.0
```

In my local machine, this container listens to incoming requests in the following URL: http://localhost:4444/

Nevertheless, I have a "connection refused" error when trying to connect that URL (http://localhost:4444/) after starting that image (using the host network) in GitHub Actions. The error I get in Java is the following:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Can I use the host network in GitHub Actions?

Comment: Please include your GHA workflow in your question. Looks like you can make use of [service containers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers) for your use case.

Comment: Using service containers is not an option for me, since the container is started programmatically using a Docker Java client. In any case, my GHA workflow is the following: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml

Comment: Right. Have you tried to run that command directly? Are there any error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed this can be done in GH Actions. The problem I experienced was the use of Xvfb. For some reason, using Xvfb does not allow us to use port 4444 in the same session.

It is solved as follows:

- Test: https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-examples/blob/main/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/selenium/remote/DockerWdmChromeCdpTest.java
- Workflow: https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-examples/blob/main/.github/workflows/docker-java.yml
- Execution: https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-examples/actions/runs/6706576135

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on this link [How to access host port from docker containe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container/48806927#48806927)  and [Can't curl to localhost](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/140)

Instead of localhost you can try http://host.docker.internal:4444/