# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8086 InfluxDb - Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have my **Node/Express** app that connects to **InfluxDB 2.0** at `http://localhost:8086` or `http://127.0.0.1/8086`.

`InfluxDB docker container` is created by someone over which I don't have any control.

In my node app, I connect to **InfluxDB** for local development as below,

**env.js**

```
{
    influxDB: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8086',  // OR http://127.0.0.1/8086
        token: 'xxxx==',
        org: "xxx",
        bucket: "xxx",
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

and it connects to **InfluxDB** to get/fetch data locally. It works fine.

Now, I create a docker image and container in which my node app works but It can't connect to **Influxdb**.

and it throws error.

> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8086

**docker-compose.yml** (for node app)

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  my-node-app:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: "mynodeapp:1.1.0"
    container_name: "mynodeapp-container"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000               <------ port at which my node app works
```

FYI, InfluxDB container looks as below,

```
influxdb:2.0.9                "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   6 days ago       Up 6 days       127.0.0.1:8086->8086/tcp
```

**What is missing** ?

Is there any change required in influxDB container or in my docker-compose file ?

Comment: You can connect using docker-compose container name not with http://localhost:8086 instead you should use http://{docker-compose-srvice name}:8086

Comment: If your application is running in a container, `localhost` refers to the current container and not anywhere else.

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand it so I tried with `127.0.0.1/8086` also but same result.

Comment: No, you did not understand. `localhost` is an alias to `127.0.0.1.`, and it won't work. How is the influxdb created? You say you have no control over it, but your container needs to be in the same docker network as the influxdb container, so if there isn't a network created for it, you have a problem. If they are created in the same compose fille though, then they share a network by default and can be connected to each other with the service name as the hostname.

Comment: I understand what you say. No influxdb was created by someone else. Not sure how to check if they are in the same network. If not, then how can I put my node container in the same network as influx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, when your application inside a Docker container attempts to connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, it is trying to connect to *itself*, not the host machine or any other container. That is why your attempts to connect to InfluxDB using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` are failing.

And Docker Compose provides [automatic service discovery within the same `docker-compose.yml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), allowing containers to communicate with each other using the service name as the hostname.

If InfluxDB is in a separate docker compose file or managed independently, your Node.js application container and the InfluxDB container must be on the same Docker network to communicate. You can create a network and attach both containers to it. If you do not have access to modify the InfluxDB container's configuration, you can still connect to an existing network if you know its name.

- Create a network (if you can influence the InfluxDB container setup): `docker network create <network-name>`
- Attach your container to the existing network by modifying your `docker-compose.yml`:

  ```yaml
  version: '3.8'
  services:
    my-node-app:
      ...
      networks:
        - default
        - existing-network

  networks:
    existing-network:
      external: true
  ```

  A `docker network ls` can list the existing networks, and you will have to find the one that includes the InfluxDB container (`docker inspect <container-name-or-id>`).

If InfluxDB is on your host machine, you can also try using Docker's [special DNS name `host.docker.internal`](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host) (for development purposes): that DNS name allows you to connect from a container back to the host machine. Update your Node.js application's configuration to use `http://host.docker.internal:8086` as the InfluxDB URL.

---

> I tried `http://host.docker.internal:8086`, but it still throws error.
>
> I'm using Docker v25.0.3, and it's an Ubuntu machine.

Then make sure [`extra_hosts`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/6ffbdbfb143880771005fb3990ba42f395873672/spec.md#extra_hosts) is correctly set up in your Docker Compose configuration. That enables the container to resolve `host.docker.internal` to the host's IP address:

```yaml
services:
  my-node-app:
    ...
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

See more with "[How to connect to the Docker host from inside a Docker container?](https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/how-to-connect-to-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container-112b4c71bc66)" from [Tim van Baarsen](https://twitter.com/TimvanBaarsen).

Make sure InfluxDB is operational and check its logs for potential issues:

- Confirm InfluxDB is running.
- Check InfluxDB logs for errors or warnings.

InfluxDB should listen on a network interface that is reachable from the Docker container, typically on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`. Check InfluxDB's binding interface: on the host, run `netstat -tuln | grep 8086` to see if InfluxDB is listening on `0.0.0.0:8086`.

Ubuntu's firewall ([ufw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomplicated_Firewall)) might be blocking connections from Docker containers. Temporarily disable the firewall to test connectivity: `sudo ufw disable`, then, after testing, `sudo ufw enable`.
If needed, allow traffic on port 8086: `sudo ufw allow 8086`

Make sure Docker's network configurations do not prevent communication. Examine network setups with `docker network inspect` and adjust if necessary.

From within the Docker container, ping `host.docker.internal` to verify DNS resolution and network routing:

```bash
docker exec -it <container_name_or_id> ping host.docker.internal
```

---

> `influxdb:2.0.9                "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   6 days ago       Up 6 days       127.0.0.1:8086->8086/tcp`

So InfluxDB is running as its own container. The presence of `127.0.0.1:8086->8086/tcp` indicates that InfluxDB is only accessible from the host machine and not directly accessible to other containers through inter-container networking.

To make InfluxDB accessible to other containers, it should not be bound only to `127.0.0.1` on the host. Instead, it should be accessible through Docker's internal networking.

If both containers (your Node app and InfluxDB) are on the same default bridge network, you can connect to InfluxDB using the container name as the hostname. However, this setup limits some Docker networking features like automatic DNS resolution across containers.

The recommended approach for inter-container communication is to create a custom network: `docker network create mynetwork`.
Attach both containers to this network by updating their respective `docker-compose.yml` files or through Docker run commands with the `--network=mynetwork` option. For the InfluxDB container, make sure it is not binding to `127.0.0.1` only.

After setting up the network, adjust your application's connection URL to use the InfluxDB container's name, e.g., `http://influxdb-container-name:8086`, replacing `influxdb-container-name` with the actual service name defined for InfluxDB in the `docker-compose.yml` or the container name if you are running containers individually without Docker Compose.

If you are managing your containers with Docker Compose, make sure both services are defined in the same `docker-compose.yml` or they are using a shared external network. Here is an example configuration for your Node app:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  my-node-app:
    ...
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.0.9
    ...
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
```

Note: If `mynetwork` is defined in another `docker-compose.yml`, set `external: true` to indicate it is defined elsewhere. Adjust your Node app's environment configuration to use the service name (`influxdb`) as part of the connection URL.

Make sure both containers are running on the same network by using `docker network inspect mynetwork`. And test the connection from your Node app to InfluxDB by using the new connection URL.

---

> I don't have access of InfluxDB yml file. I just get the container that's it.
> What I have done is:
>
> - I checked what is the network of influxdb. If it is eg `greengrass` (network).
> - In node's docker-compose file, I added : `network_mode:"greengrass"`, and changed URL as `127.10.0.1:8086` (I found this IP address from influxdb container).
>
> With these two changes when I checked, yes it worked.
>
> Now the only problem is I can't put IP like it. I don't know if is a static or dynamic IP.

[Docker networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/) provide an isolated networking environment for containers. When containers are attached to the same network, they can communicate with each other using the container name as the hostname. That capability eliminates the need for static IP addresses since Docker's internal DNS resolver allows containers to find each other by name.

By adding the `greengrass` network to the Node.js application's `docker-compose.yml`, you placed both containers on the same network. That is achieved with the `networks` configuration, marking `greengrass` as an `external` network, which means it is defined outside of the current Docker Compose file but can be connected to.
See also the [`docker network`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/network/) command.

You can then update the connection URL in the Node.js application's configuration to use the InfluxDB service name (`http://influxDB_service_name:8086`). That service name corresponds to the name or identifier used within the Docker network to refer to the InfluxDB container. Docker resolves this name to the container's current IP address within the `greengrass` network, making sure the Node.js application can reach InfluxDB regardless of its IP address.

Since Docker's networking provides name-based resolution, the containers can communicate without needing to know each other's IP addresses. This is more robust against changes in IP addresses, which can occur when containers are restarted or redeployed. Configurations are simplified, and dependencies on specific network configurations are reduced. IT also provides isolation between groups of containers, limiting which containers can communicate with each other. That enhances security and reduces the risk of unintended interactions between containers.

Comment: I tried `http://host.docker.internal:8086` but it still throws error.

Comment: @micronyks What version of Docker are you running? On which host OS?

Comment: I'm using v25.0.3 and it's ubuntu machine.

Comment: fyi, `influxdb:2.0.9                "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   6 days ago       Up 6 days       127.0.0.1:8086->8086/tcp`

Comment: @micronyks OK So influxdb is running in its own container (the InfluxDB's binding interface advice would still stand, though)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257211/discussion-between-vonc-and-micronyks).

Answer (score 1):

Look at @VonC's answer and explanation.

**How did I resolve it**?

Steps that I followed,

1. I checked network information in **InfluxDB** container by running below command

   docker container inspect container_id

and check for `Networks section`

```
...
...
"Networks": {
                "greengrass": {        <###### This is important
                    ...
                    ...
                 }
             }
...
...
```

2. In node's **docker-compose.yml** file, I added `network` information as follow,

   ```
   version: '3.8'
   services:
     my-node-app:
       build:
         context: ../
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
       image: "mynodeapp:1.1.0"
       container_name: "mynodeapp-container"
       ports:
         - 5000:5000

    // I added below code snippet

       networks:
         - greengrass                     <####### I got it from InfluxDB container as pointed out above

   networks:
     greengrass
       external: true
   ```
3. changed url in **env.js** as below,

   ```
    {
     influxDB: {
         url: 'http://influxDB_service_name:8086', <#### add influxdb service name
         token: 'xxxx==',
         ...
         ...
    }
   ```

Comment: I have edited my answer to add some explanation on this setup.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how containers work. You can think of a container as it's own Linux system, so unless InfluxDB is inside the node app container, both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` (which is also localhost) will not work.

Typically in a deployment like yours you would want to connect to a separate InfluxDB container so the url will end up being something like `http://mynodeapp-db:8086` if `mynodeapp-db` is the name of the database container. See [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb) for more details.

If you are running the database on the host machine and your app in a container, you will want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container).

You need to read up on Docker networks if you plan on developing with Docker. It can be slightly confusing at first but the documentation is robust.

Comment: I tried this way but no success...